# How to make a normal apk with .dex inside it from an apk which is odexed?

Tags: applications, apk, odex

I had a file manager provided by my manufacturer as a system app.

it was odexed.

i have its apk and odex file both.

I installed a custom rom now and want to install that filemanager. how do i do this? how can i make a normal deodexed file from the odexd one?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't the system generate a .dex file when you run an app without one?

Comment: It doesnt install itself! So i dont reach the run state at all!

Comment: Oh I see, you have to deodex.  I haven't done it but here's a starting point: http://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/DeodexInstructions